# JAVA rest webservice returning 404 error, deployed on Tomcat in Linux CentOS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I deployed the JAVA restful web service on Tomcat 7 on Linux CentOS server (VPS). It is returning error:

[image: Error 404:]

The same webservice deployed on tomcat7 in localhost is running fine.

I created simple webservice following the tutorialspoint link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm

**source code:**

```
package com.studentinfo;  

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
   }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>studentinfo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>studentinfo rest service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.studentinfo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>studentinfo rest service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Jersey version is 1.19
JDK version is jdk1.7.0_79

The web service is deployed on Tomcat7 in linux CentOS server. The same webservice is running fine on localhost on windows machine. 
Default examples deployed on tomcat can be accessed fine too.
Is there any configuration that needs to be considered in case of linux server?

Comment: Are you trying to get the correct file?

Comment: The same webservice can be accessed correctly when hosted on localhost tomcat

Comment: The issue has been fixed. As it was working fine on my local host. I found that the version of JDK on my local machine is 1.7.0_51. I installed the same on linux machine. Also in webapps\<webservice>\WEB_INF\lib all the required JARs were not present.